# On Hilbert polynomials

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

The sequence of Hilbert polynomials is defined by :
$$H_0=1,\ \\ H_n(X)=\frac{X(X-1)...(X-n+1)}{n!}\ ,n>0$$
How can we prove the following identity :
$$H_n(X+Y)=\sum_{k=0}^nH_k(X)H_{n-k}(Y)$$

Comment: If we have a two polynomials in variables $x, y$ with degree $m, n$ in $x, y$ then it is sufficient to check their equality on a set of $(m+1)(n+1)$ tuples $(x, y) $ such that these tuples have $m+1$ different values of $x$ and $(n+1)$ different values of $y$. In your case by the usual binomial theorem the above identity holds for an infinite number of values of $X, Y$ when $X, Y$ are positive integers.

Comment: This answered your question [Proof: $\binom{x+y+n-1}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{x+n-k-1}{n-k} \binom{y+k-1}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317468/proof-binomxyn-1n-sum-k-0n-binomxn-k-1n-k-binomyk-1k), since $H_n(X)=(-1)^n\binom{-X+n-1}n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A little context:** This is Vandermonde's identity. Consider the notation $$H_n(X)=\frac{X^{\underline{n}}}{n!},$$ where $X^{\underline{n}}=X(X-1)\cdots (X-n+1).$ Essentially, $H_n(X)=\binom{X}{n}$ if you see it in that way. So what you are proving is $$\binom{X+Y}{n}=\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{X}{k}\binom{Y}{n-k}.$$

**Hint:** What if you show it for integers(perhaps using binomial theorem $(1+z)^{x+y}=(1+z)^x(1+z)^y$ and expanding for $z.$). Try to extend it for rationals and use approximation to extend it for reals.

Comment: Yes but how can i prove it ?

Comment: If you already have the generalized binomial theorem, use the equality that is in the hint for general $x$ and $y.$ If not, use that to show it for rationals. Notice that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: Once we prove the equality of two polynomials for an infinite number of values of the each of the variables the polynomials are identically equal. The case of positive integers thus settles it for all values.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ H_{k}\left(X\right)=\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-j\right)} $$

Let's prove by induction that : $$ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(X+Y-j\right)}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{k-j-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}} $$

The statement holds for $ k=1 \cdot $

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, assuming that the statement holds for $ k=n $, let's prove that the statement holds for $ k=n+1 : $

\begin{aligned} \small\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\left(X+Y-k\right)}&\small=\left(X+Y-n\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(X+Y-k\right)}\\ &\small=\left(X+Y-n\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}}\\ &\small=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\left(X-k\right)\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\left(Y-n+k\right)\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}}\\ &\small=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}} \\ &\small=\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(X-i\right)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(Y-i\right)}\\ &\small=\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(X-i\right)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k-1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(Y-i\right)}\\ &\small=\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(X-i\right)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left[\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}\right]\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(Y-i\right)}\\ &\small=\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(X-i\right)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n+1}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}+\prod_{i=0}^{n}{\left(Y-i\right)}\\ \small\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\left(X+Y-k\right)}&\small=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+1}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k}{\left(Y-i\right)}}\end{aligned}

Hence : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(X+Y-k\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(X-i\right)}\prod_{i=0}^{n-k-1}{\left(Y-i\right)}} $$

Dividing both sides by $ n! $, we get that : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ H_{n}\left(X+Y\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{H_{k}\left(X\right)H_{n-k}\left(Y\right)} $$