# Polynomial Summation Identity

Tags: polynomials, summation

Let $P_{0}(x) = 1$ and for natural $n > 0 $ :  $$P_{n}(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(1 -  \frac{1 - x}{i})$$
Prove that for $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$P_{n}(x + y) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}P_{i}(x)P_{n-i}(y)$$
Nothing seems to work, tried induction, calculating individual terms, proving they share roots, summing up the identities together etc.

Comment: What are you familiar with?  Where did you get this problem from / what techniques are you expecting to use?

Comment: Came across it trying to prove something about arithmetic functions. Preferably something simple.

Comment: @AnneBauval Not quite. You want $x+i -1$, not $x-i + 1$. It's ${ x + n -1 \choose i}$.

Comment: Observe that $P_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{ x+i - 1 } { i} ={ x+n-1 \choose n} $. The identity is thus restated as

$$ { x + y + n - 1 \choose n } = \sum_{i=0}^n { x + i - 1 \choose i} { y + n-i - 1 \choose n - i }. $$  See a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317468/proof-binomxyn-1n-sum-k-0n-binomxn-k-1n-k-binomyk-1k?noredirect=1), or ideally figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you that's it.

Comment: @CalvinLin ["My" duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667238) (which unfortunately disappeared when "yours" closed this post) was in fact equivalent, since $P_n(X)=(-1)^nH_n(-X).$ I shall vote to close the former (more recent: 2020) as a duplicate of the latter (2019).